# Decompound a Compound Probability Distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, convolution, integral, compound-distributions

I am trying to figure out how to *deconvolve* or *decompound* a compound probability density function - knowing one of the distributions and having samples from the compound distribution.

Assume I only know that the my distribution arises as a continuous mixture of a Poisson and an unknown distribution $g$:
$$ f(k) = \int_0^\infty f_{\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)}(k) \cdot g(\lambda) \; \mathrm{d}\lambda $$
where $g$ is a Gamma distribution in the case of a Negative Binomial distribution $f$.

Now, given samples from $f(k)$ (not necessarily from a NB distribution), what is the best way or what algorithms are used to approximate/estimate $g(\lambda)$, i.e. deconvolve the integral?

I already looked in the [Panjer recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panjer_recursion) and [this paper](https://www.ivfm.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/stochastik/Publications/Gruebel/rg_Decompounding_Poisson_random_sums.pdf), but if I understood them correctly both don't seem to help in my case.

Happy about any suggestions!

Comment: My personal first reaction would be the expectation maximization algorithm, but I'm whistling in the dark here...

Comment: Thanks! Unclear to me how such an approach would look like. Could you give me a rough idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic problem that arises in empirical Bayes theory.
The problem of estimating $g$ non-parametrically for a Poisson mixture was considered in the very first paper that coined the term "empirical Bayes":

Robbins, Herbert. An empirical Bayes approach to statistics. *Proceedings of the Third Berkeley Symposium on Mathematical Statistics and Probability*, 1954–1955, vol. I, pp. 157–163. University of California Press, Berkeley and Los Angeles, 1956.

Nowadays people usually take a more parametric approach and Herbert's 1956 method is not much used in practice.
Empirical Bayes inference is not sensitive to the exact shape of $g$ so it is far easier and just as effective to make some parametric assumptions about $g$.
This is called "parametric empirical Bayes".
For the Poisson mixture, the most common and most convenient assumption is to assume that $g$ is a gamma distribution, in which case the mixture has a closed form expression called the "negative binomial" distribution.

A recent very general approach from Bradley Efron does not make parametric assumptions about $g$ but assumes that it can be built up from spline modelling in the space of log moment generating functions.
This leads to a very general type of exponential family formulation:

Narasimhan, B., & Efron, B. (2020). deconvolveR: A G-Modeling Program for Deconvolution and Empirical Bayes Estimation. *Journal of Statistical Software*, 94(11), 1 - 20. https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v094i11

Efron B (2016). Empirical Bayes deconvolution estimates. *Biometrika*, 103(1), 1–20.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/biomet/asv068

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, both papers assume that $g$ is a distribution of the exponential family, but as they say in the paper more flexibility is pretty expensive.

Comment: @N8_Coder The papers assume that $g$ belongs to *an* exponential family not *the* exponential family. Assuming an exponential family is no restriction at all because all probability distributions of any shape at all belong to an exponential family. The only requirement is that they have an finite moment generating function.

Comment: Gordon Smyth Could you provide some reference on the distinction between “the” and “an exponential family”? I always thought that “the exponential family” is just casual use of language and means the same...

Comment: @jacques There's no such thing as "the exponential family" so there won't be any references on it. OP clearly believed that the use of exponential families was a restriction, when it is not, so it is not just casual language.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! One follow-up question: Assume I predict $n$ samples for $g(\theta)$ in eq. (7) in the first paper (equal to $g(\lambda)$ above). Is there any way to compute the likelihood of these samples, i.e. how well do they produce the observed $f_k$? Sorry, if I did not find it in the paper.

Comment: @N8_Coder No there isn't. If you insist on a non-parametric estimate of $g$ then you can't compute likelihoods or make predictions. If you want to do these things, then use a parametric $g$.

Comment: @N8_Coder In practice, it is almost impossible to distinguish one compound Poisson distribution from another, so seeking generality for $g$ IMO has little potential benefit.

Comment: "it is almost impossible to distinguish one compound Poisson distribution from another", what do you mean by that? Depending on the differences between various $g$, the compound distributions will also look pretty different...

Comment: @N8_Coder I meant just what said. Any two compound Poisson distributions will be far more similar than the two $g$-mixing distributions that produced them, so any subtle differences in $g$-distributions will be lost. You say that "the compound distributions will also look pretty different" but have you tried or are you just making assumptions?

Comment: @N8_Coder It is easy to estimate the mean and variance of $g$ from the mean and variance of the compound distribution. Now consider $g_1$ and $g_2$ that both have support on the positive reals and have the same mean and variance. Can you distinguish the two resulting compound distributions? You will find that you cannot reliably do so unless you have an enormous amount of data. For example, a gamma $g_1$ and a log-normal $g_2$ lead to indistinguishable compound distributions if $g_1$ and $g_2$ have the same mean and variance.

Comment: That makes sense, sorry, I got you wrong here!
One final questions: you say " [...] can be built up from spline modelling in the space of log moment generating functions". As far as I can see in the paper they always do spline modelling in the space of the support set $\tau$, i.e $Q=ns(\tau, df)$? Thanks in advance!